# OAuth 2 bearer Authorization header

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, oauth-2.0, nsurlrequest

With an update to the client's API the HTTPBasicAuthication method has been replace with a OAuth2 `Bearer` Authorization header.

With the old API I would do the following:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.account.username 
                                                         password:self.account.token 
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSURLProtectionSpace *space = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:kAPIHost
                                                                    port:443
                                                                protocol:NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPS
                                                                   realm:@"my-api"
                                                    authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];
```

But this will not work with the `Bearer` header.

Now normally I would just add the header my self by adding it like so:

```
NSString *authorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",self.account.token];
[urlRequest setValue:authorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

But the problem with this solutions is that the API redirect most of the calls to other URLs, this has to do with security.
After the `NSURLRequest` gets redirected the Authorization header is removed from the request and since I'm unable to add the Bearer method to the `NSURLCredentialStorage` it can't authenticate any more after being redirected.

What would be a good solutions? I can only think to catch the redirect and modify the `NSURLRequest` so it does include the `Bearer` header. But how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well after much research I found out that I will just have to replace the `NSURLRequest` when a call is redirected.

Not as nice as I would like it to be, but is does work.

I used `AFNetworking` and added the  redirect block, then check wether the `Authorization` header is still set if not I create a new `NSMutableURLRequest` and set all the properties to match the old request (I know I could have just created a mutable copy):

```
[requestOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {

    if ([request.allHTTPHeaderFields objectForKey:@"Authorization"] != nil) {
        return request;
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:request.URL cachePolicy:request.cachePolicy timeoutInterval:request.timeoutInterval];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", self.account.token];
    [urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    return  urlRequest;

}];
```

Comment: you are a legend. I encountered the same problem and handling the redirect fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using AFNetworking Library

Find **AFHttpClient.m** and you have a method

```
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token {
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=\"%@\"", token]];
}
```

replace this method with the following or if you need it for back compatibility keep it an add with a different name and use that name

```
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token {
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token]];
}
```

then make the request with oauth access token. (Following is a GET method service)

```
    NSURL *url = [EFServiceUrlProvider getServiceUrlForMethod:methodName];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    [httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"add your access token here"];

    [httpClient getPath:@"" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //
    }];
```

## Updated

---

Use Oauth2 Client on AFNetworking written by matt

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client

Comment: No not when the request is redirected, then you will loose the bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be having this issue with Django rest framework and the routers the problem might be related to the trailing slash being clipped by the NSUrlRequest. if the trailing slash is clipped then django will have to redirect your request, to avoid this you can use Trailing_slash = True like this

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

That way not your authorization header nor your parameters will get lost.

Hope this saves somebody some time.

Comment: No Django, but ASP.net and I've also see it with PHP. As soon as a URL redirect occurs the `Authorization` is cleared. This is normal behavior and after a 403 is received the call be done again with the `Authorization` header. Problem is that `bearer` header are not supported very well.

Comment: Wow. We have been using Django rest and freaking out trying to figure why IOS was not sending the Authorization token header, and this was it, NSURLRequest was removing the trailing slash