# Get access to user data from box cloud (box.com) in ios

Tags: ios, cloud, box-api

I'm trying to get data from box user account.
For now i have generated the token but i can't get the root folder content (for example).

to get the token, i get the ticket with this request:

```
https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key=BoxApiKey
```

After that i call a webView in my application to load this page :

```
https://m.box.com/api/1.0/auth/ticket
```

after the user log successfully i parse the web page and extract the token.

now come problems, i can't get the root folder content.
this is what i try with AFNetworking:

1. i add this methode in the AFHTTPClient class (as suggested [her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091341/oauth-2-bearer-authorization-header))

   ```
   -(void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithTokenBearer:(NSString *)token
   {
      [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token]];
   }
   ```
2. my call:

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0"];
   AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
   [httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithTokenBearer:token];


   [httpClient postPath:@"" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *e) {
       NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", e.localizedDescription);
   }];
   ```

But i have this localizedDescription :

```
[HTTPClient Error]: Expected status code in (200-299), got 401
```

can you help me to resolve this? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an issue because the header style you're using is OAuth 2, and the token you have is V1 Auth.

If you're using this header

```
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

You need to get the token through the `[OAuth 2 process][1]`

However, if you're using this header

```
Authorization BoxAuth api_key={api key}&auth_token={v1 auth token}
```

You need to get the token through the V1 auth process, which is the one you've outlined.

As a sidenote, you should try to use the OAuth 2 process, as the V1 process is going to be deprecated later this year.